How can I make this material static on the figure? Now the figure slides through it
I want to make this so that the texture moves with the figure. Right now the figure kind of slides through it.



@MartynasŽiemys Looking at the revision history it says you have edited the "Download the Blend" image into the question but without a link to the file. Why or what happened there?

Hi @GordonBrinkmann Are you having trouble opening the file? It downloads and opens for me fine. I'm not exactly sure what the issue is.

The question was edited 9 hours ago and again 7 hours ago. 9 hours ago I wrote my comment, there was only the image, no link to the blend file. This was added 7 hours ago. Now it works for me too.

Don't use the Object output of the Texture Coordinate because the texture won't follow once the object is animated, instead use Generated and stretch the texture in the Mapping node.

@Gorgious It definitely fixes the problem, this can easily be tested - no need for speculation.

Hehe sorry for confusion. TIL Generated coordinates follow armature deformation. :)

Yup. That worked. Thank you very much!
